# jpa Hibernate make schema name configurable in Entity class

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I was developing a simple Spring Boot application in which, jpa + Hibernate is user for accessing my data source, which is Oracle DB. The entity class is given below.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="MY_SCHEMA.MY_DB") 
    public class Member implements Serializable {
    .............
    }
```

Currently my project doesn't have any persistence.xml. The problem is, I need to make the schema name (MY_SCHEMA) inside @Table annotation configurable, that is getting the schema value from application.properties file on run time.

I have tried by adding `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=schema` option in application.properties file. But all in vain.

### Update

Have added more details in another question [Hibernate how to make schema name configurable for entity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031560/hibernate-how-to-make-schema-name-configurable-for-entity-class)

Comment: Why put a schema name as part of the table name, when it is not part of the table name? `@Table` has "schema"

Answer (score 1):

Below are the available options that can be used for your purpose of creating table in a particular Schema. mention the schema name in the schema field.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE_NAME", schema= "MY_SCHEMA_NAME")
public class Myclass {
```

Also you can define the schema name in the DB URL as below using the application.properties file. you need to update the values as per your needs.

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MY_SCHEMA_NAME?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

Comment: could you please share me the code what you have tried ?