# Hibernate how to make schema name configurable for entity class

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have been tying to make the schema name in Entity class configurable. The code which I tried for my springboot applicqtion is given below.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Employee", schema=Employee.schemaName)
             public class Employee implements Serializable {
        @Autowired
        private static Environment env;
        public static String schema =env.getProperty("databaseSchema");
        public static final String schemaName = schema; 
        ..........
        }
```

Here I was trying to get the schema name from my configuration file using Environment object and set the value to schema inside @Table annotation. But I'm getting an error at the schema name in @Table annotation that "The value for annotation attribute Table.schema must be a constant expression". And if I remove the static final from the variables schema and schemaName, then also am getting an error inside @Table that "cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Employee.schemaName". Is there any way by which I can make the schema name configurable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Annotations require constants values in order to declare its parameters

Comment: Like having an `orm.xml` with the schema name defined there? so then you can start up the EMF with whichever `orm.xml` file you want to work with

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Hibernate multi-tenancy

see the documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy)

Multi-tenancy allows a single application instance to be served for multiple tenants on a single hosting server. This is usually performed by either Separating databases, Separating schemas or Sharing schemas.